# Why my output in mips random numbers in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

THIS IS MY CODE it's simple but the output print as random! it's suppose to print 21

```
.data
            age: .word 21

.globl main

main:

.text
li $v0, 1
la $a0, age
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

and, this is my output

268500992

-- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --

Comment: You only ever put the address of `age` into a register, and you don't dereference that address.  Also, your `main` label is `.data`, not in `.text` where the function body is!

Comment: It is not a random number!  When you see numbers like that, use a programmer's calculator to turn it into hex: 268500992 base 10 is 1001 0000 base 16/hex.  That is the address of the first byte of the .data section.  You're printing an address.  If you want to fetch the value to print, use `lw` instead of `la` (or dereference the address after the `la`).

Answer (score 1):

To print an integer, you have to make syscall #1 instead of syscall #4. Secondly, your .text is inside the main function, which is not right. Here is the revised code:

```
    .data
    age: .word  21

    .text
    .globl main

    main:

    li $v0, 1
    lw $a0, age
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```